# How to Create a new Version Programmatically in Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a choice field called stage lets assume it has following values used as a dropdown

```
stage1
stage2
stage3
```

on change of stage I would like to record TimeStamp and Who updated the item information

How can I do it on my List without creating any other list, I think using Versioning I can add a new version whenever before and after properties are change on that Field.

```
//ItemUpdating Event 
if(properties.ListItem["Stage"] != properties.AfterProperties["Stage"])
{
   //Create a Version;
}
```

I cannot find how to create a version here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have versioning enabled, every time you call [SPListItem.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.update.aspx) method, SharePoint automatically creates new version.

If you don't want new version to be created, call [UpdateOverwriteVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.updateoverwriteversion.aspx).

If you don't want to modify Modified By and Modified fields, then call [SystemUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461526.aspx) (see overloaded [SystemUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms481195.aspx), where you pass argument also not to create new version).

Comment: thanks for the help but I am having a Event Handler for the List where I am check weather to create a version or not Since I now know how to disable versioning but I am unable to apply it , where do i actually do it in ItemUpdated or ItemUpdating or eleswhere ?

Comment: Versioning is enabled in the list settings. Settings -> List Settings -> Versioning Settings

Comment: You usally do not check weather to create version or not - just call the update method. If versioning will be enabled - version will be created. If not enabled - not created.

UpdateOverwriteVersion and SystemUpdate methods are EXCEPTIONAL and you use them only to specify that you REALLY do not want to create new version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. If you have versionning enabled, don't you have this info already under version history? Why do you need to develop anything new?

Comment: I need this because I am trying to create a log which can record whenever there is the change in "Stage" of the item i am not bothered about other changes but since Enabling Versioning will track any change made to the item it does not fit in.

Comment: Hmm, how about programmatically deleting versions if the Stage was not changed in them? let's say, an event receiver?